# function (or procedure) to perform push and pop In Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

This Is Practice But I Don't Have Any Idea How To Solve And Write It !

**Question: Write Pakhage that perform *push* and *pop* correctly.**
No Another Data or Value In The Question.
**EDITED:** The forgotten part of the question that was not initially assigned was to write a sample package with the desired data that could show how POP and PUSH worked.

```
create or replace package pushpop_demo as
    procedure push(val varchar2);
    function  pop return varchar2;
    function  stack_depth return simple_integer;
end pushpop_demo;
/
```

Comment: Not much to go on. Presumably this refers to array processing, in which case you could have a collection defined in a package body, along with procedures to add an element (push) and retrieve the last element from it (pop). If that's the case then there is no SQL involved, only PL/SQL.

Comment: I'd read it as reading and writing data to a table rather than using a collection but @WilliamRobertson's reading is certainly reasonable.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Exactly I want the PL/SQL solution. But I have no idea. Especially for the question that does not specify a parameter, table or anything else. Just want to be solved What I Wrote In Question !

Comment: _" Just want to be solved What I Wrote In Question !"_   Not possible without knowing exactly what kind of structure is to be 'pushed' and 'popped'.

Comment: Have a look at dbms_aq (Advanced Queue). The amount of information in the question suggests you’re looking for a quick and simple solution, so maybe you aren’t worried about multiple users (in which case using a database for this is a bit weird).

Comment: @EdStevens In fact, it was a package with custom data that showed how Pop and Push workes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as a coding exercise, I had in mind something like this:

```
create or replace package pushpop_demo as
    procedure push(val varchar2);
    function  pop return varchar2;
    function  stack_depth return simple_integer;
end pushpop_demo;
/
```

```
create or replace package body pushpop_demo as
    subtype my_string_subtype is varchar2(100);
    type varchar2_ntt is table of my_string_subtype;
    stuff varchar2_ntt := varchar2_ntt();

    procedure push(val varchar2)
    is
    begin
        stuff.extend;
        stuff(stuff.last) := val;
    end push;

    function pop return varchar2
    is
        val my_string_subtype;
    begin
        if stuff is not empty then
            val := stuff(stuff.last);
            stuff.delete(stuff.last);
        end if;

        return val;
    end pop;

    -- Report the number of items in the stack
    function stack_depth return simple_integer
    is
    begin
        return stuff.count;
    end stack_depth;
end pushpop_demo;
/
```

Function `stack_depth` isn't really needed, but I thought it might be interesting to be able to report the number of items currently pushed.

Demo:

```
begin
    pushpop_demo.push(val => 'Kittens');
    pushpop_demo.push(val => 'Puppies');
    pushpop_demo.push(val => 'Hamsters');

    dbms_output.put_line('Items in stack: '||pushpop_demo.stack_level());

    dbms_output.put_line(pushpop_demo.pop());
    dbms_output.put_line(pushpop_demo.pop());
    dbms_output.put_line(pushpop_demo.pop());

    dbms_output.put_line('Items in stack: '||pushpop_demo.stack_level());
end;
/
```

Output:

```
Items in stack: 3
Hamsters
Puppies
Kittens
Items in stack: 0
```